# Rise of Domestic Terror Groups in the US

Tags: united-states, terrorism

Do the formation of domestic terror groups in the US, (Symbionese Liberation Army, Animal Liberation Front (ALF), Environmental Liberation Front (ELF), Black Panthers, the Weathermen, the KKK, other white supremacist groups, The Fuerzas Armadas de Liberación Nacional (English: Armed Forces of National Liberation, FALN), the Students for a Democratic Society, and others on the right and the left or maybe the outfield) share any commonalities:

- in formation, organization and the like; or
- societal or [phenomenographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenography) causes

What I am not interested in is ideological similarities.  Those are pretty well documented, both the differences and the similarities.

Comment: Please define "rise". Do you mean "existence"? Did the weatherman reunite? As for the question, I think this is less politics and much more psychology.

Comment: @blip By rise I mean start.  I'm really interested in similarities at inception and the beginning of organization.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd suggest starting the question as "Did the formation of..." to make it a little clearer as several of those groups no longer even exist or if they do, they actually exist in a much lesser capacity than previously.

Comment: @blip done.  That's right.  Actually one has come back, the New Black Panther party.   All of these I think are less active or no longer in existence compared to their heyday

Answer (score 1):

Do the formation of these groups share any similarities? Of course they do! There is a ton of research out there on exactly this subject, but thankfully the Journal of Strategic Studies published a literature review in 2011 (see the article for free [here](http://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1139&context=jss)).

I'd recommended reading the article for all the gritty details, but in general:

- Extremists (whether individuals or organizations) form within existing social movements. The first step is the creation of a social movement. Success at this stage relies on some macro-level social factors, as well as some lower-level factors (social networks, emotion, identity).
- Second, the social movement has to be maintained long enough to gestate extremists. At this level, successful social movements operate at a rational level: they recruit members, form organizational structures, accumulate resources, etc.
- Third, a group within the larger social movement splinters off and radicalizes. Although not fully covered in the article, one of the promising areas of research on this area relies on social networks. Individuals are surrounded by people who echo their beliefs and values, and over time they amplify each other's views until they become extreme. Their network also allows them to "broadcast" their ideas to sympathetic listeners without fear of reprisal.

This is a 9,000 foot view: there is a lot of research about each one of these steps.  Tons of people have made entire careers out of focusing on just one of them.

As a final passing note, some of the comments on this question focus on ideology. It's worth noting that ideology is no longer believed to be a causal factor in extremism. Basically, extremism and terrorism are more about *how you think* than *what you think*. Many people who share the views of terrorists will never commit any kind of extreme or terrorist act. Conversely, many terrorists or extremists have no particularly unusual beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have cites right now since this mostly comes from listening to various counter-terrorism themed podcasts over the years (e.g. DHS type stuff, Stratfor); but the general themes seem to be:

- The rise of Internet and social networking greatly enables:

  - self-radicalisation of lone wolf types. No matter what one's ideology, it's easy to come by the material to make your beliefs stronger.
  - greatly simplifies social organization of more organized types, including ability to communicate without being physically co-located.
  - Enables people to learn the tools of the "trade". In the past, to train to commit an attack, you had to travel to a terrorist training camp. Today, you fire up BitTorrent client or even a web browser, and Google for instructions on tactics, propaganda, weapons making etc...
- 24x7 news cycle. Terrorist attacks have far more societal impact due to increased coverage/attention.
- People in western liberal democracies grew - as a society and individuals - greatly more risk averse than was the norm 50 or 100 years ago. This makes a potential threat and fear of a terrorist attack far more impactful (and excepting 9/11, a vast majority of terror attacks have very low impact from the attack itself, it's the fear of further attacks that is their main meaningful effect).
- History teaches us things. Unfortunately, it also teaches things to people who observed the last 40 years of human history and discovered that terrorism, unfortunately, **can work and be an effective tool** for achieving one's political goal. (previous bullet points cover some of the reasons its efficacy increased; there are also political factors but they are more controversial).

  - Bundled up here are also false, but compelling lessons ("Gavrila Princip caused World War I by killing Archduke Ferdinand" - it's absolute nonsense to anyone familiar with history or geopolitics, but it's such a *compelling* story if you're contemplating being a terrorist).

Comment: The first bullet point seems very apt. Also a little ironic given the site we're on. :) But good answer.

Comment: While good information, this doesn't really explore commonalities.  And note a great number of terrorist groups arose in the 60s and 70s when many of your points address today.

Comment: @KDog - you need to clarify the timeframes in the question.

Comment: @user4012  It doesn't matter what the time frames are.  I would be ok contrasting and comparing the anti-free speech domestic terrorism today we are seeing at Berkeley and NYU with the SDS of the 60s.  If anything, those earlier groups were more deadly.  Just want to know what they had/have in common.

Comment: @KDog - the belief that the violent means justify the ends seems like a common thread, but it's kind of too obvious to point out